# activate/deactivate tab in the rightsidebar of a shinydashboardplus at click on left sidebar menu item

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I'm building a Shiny app using the great `ShinyDashoardPlus` package (styled with a theme from the `Dashboardthemes` package) that has three `tabItems` holding the contents for the three sections of the app (section A, section B, and section C), accessible through the `sidebarMenu` in the left `dashboardSidebar`, and a right sidebar with two tabs (implemented as `rightSidebarTabContent` with the following ids: `T_A` and `T_B`) holding controls to explore further the contents of sections A and B respectively.

Since the `rightSidebarTabContent` `T_A` is only relevant for `section A`, and `rightSidebarTabContent` `T_B` is only relevant for `section B`, I would like that (1) the user's **click on the left sidebar menu items A or B** could **activate the corresponding tab in the right sidebar**. Moreover, since none of the `rightSidebarTabContents` is relevant in `section C`, I'd also like that (2) the user's **click on the on the left sidebar menu item C** could **close the rightsidebar**, if it is open.

I've found a possible hint on how to solve my problems  ([Automatic rightSidebar popup when menuItem is clicked in shinydashboardPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876446/automatic-rightsidebar-popup-when-menuitem-is-clicked-in-shinydashboardplus)), and I was indeed able to partially solve my first problem adding/removing some CSS class via `shinyjs` to activate a part of the different tabs in the `rightSidebar` at click on the `menuItems`.

As I said, this solution partially works for my first issue, although only the `rightSidebarTabContent` lower part is activated/deactivated in this way, but not the tab header with the icons for navigating between them.  Moreover, possibly due to extra CSS classes added when I apply the shinydashboard theme "dark", I'm not able to toggle the closing of the `rightSidebar` at click on `section C` menu item (issue # 2).

To summarize:

1. Right sidebar item `T_A` should expand when left sidebar item `section A` is selected. Likewise for `T_A` and `section B`.
2. The right sidebar should collapse when `section C` is selected on the left sidebar

Can anyone please help with this? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(dashboardthemes)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "Dashboard",
    enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
    rightSidebarIcon = "info-circle"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Section A", tabName = "Section_A", icon = icon("map")),
      menuItem("Section B", tabName = "Section_B", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Section C", tabName = "Section_C", icon = icon( "gears")),
      id = "nav"
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    shinyDashboardThemes(
      theme = "grey_dark"
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_A",
        p("Some content for section A")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_B",
        p("Some content for section B")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_C",
        p("Some content for section C"))
      )
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
    background = "dark",
    rightSidebarTabContent(
      id = "T_A",
      title = "Tab for section A",
      icon = "desktop",
      active = TRUE,
      p("Some content frelevant for section A"),
      sliderInput(
        "obs",
        "Number of observations:",
        min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
      )
    ),
    rightSidebarTabContent(
      id = "T_B",
      title = "Tab for section B",
      p("Some content frelevant for section B"),
      textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary")
    )
  ),
  title = "Right Sidebar"
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_A"){
      message("Section A has been selected")
      shinyjs::removeClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_A-tab", class = "tab-pane")
      shinyjs::removeClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_B-tab", class = "tab-pane active")
      shinyjs::addClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_A-tab", class = "tab-pane active")
      shinyjs::addClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_B-tab", class = "tab-pane")
    }
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_B"){
      message("Section B has been selected")
      shinyjs::removeClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_B-tab", class = "tab-pane")
      shinyjs::removeClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_A-tab", class = "tab-pane active")
      shinyjs::addClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_B-tab", class = "tab-pane active")
      shinyjs::addClass(id = "control-sidebar-T_A-tab", class = "tab-pane")
    }
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_C"){
      message("Section C has been selected")
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar-open aside.control-sidebar-dark", class = "control-sidebar-open aside.control-sidebar-dark-open")
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar")
    }
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can render your right sidebar items reactively through `renderUI` instead of modifying the `CSS`. Inside `rightSidebar` we can place a single `uiOutput` that would get populated with different contents dependent on the chosen item in the left sidebar. Note that this is a partial solution. The sidebar, once expanded, will still not collapse when selecting `section C` in the left sidebar. [See edit below that addresses collapsing of the right sidebar.]

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(dashboardthemes)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  useShinyjs(),
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "Dashboard",
    enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
    rightSidebarIcon = "info-circle"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Section A", tabName = "Section_A", icon = icon("map")),
      menuItem("Section B", tabName = "Section_B", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Section C", tabName = "Section_C", icon = icon( "gears")),
      id = "nav"
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    shinyDashboardThemes(
      theme = "grey_dark"
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_A",
        p("Some content for section A")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_B",
        p("Some content for section B")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_C",
        p("Some content for section C"))
    )
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
    background = "dark",
    uiOutput("side_bar"),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_A"){
      message("Section A has been selected")
      # added in edit
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      output$side_bar <- renderUI({
        rightSidebarTabContent(
          id = "T_A",
          title = "Tab for section A",
          p("Some content relevant for section A"),
          sliderInput(
            "obs",
            "Number of observations:",
            min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
          )
        )
      })
    }
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_B"){
      message("Section B has been selected")
      # added in edit
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      output$side_bar <- renderUI({
        rightSidebarTabContent(
          id = "T_B",
          title = "Tab for section B",
          p("Some content relevant for section B"),
          textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary")
        )
      })
    }

    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_C"){
      message("Section C has been selected")
      # added in edit
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")

      output$side_bar <- renderUI({ div() })
    }
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit: Collapse the right sidebar when `section C` is clicked**. After reading the post you linked more carefully, you can simply add

```
shinyjs::addClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")
```

in your observer when `section A` and `section B` are selected, and add

```
shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "aside.control-sidebar", class = "control-sidebar-open")
```

when `section C` is selected.

Then the right sidebar will expand and collapse based on selections in the left sidebar.

A gif of the behavior:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer! Your solutions indeed partially solve my issues, but I've noticed a couple of side effects I'd like to avoid.
First, when one is in section A or B it is no longer possible to close the right sidebar. Clicking on the icon in the header has not effect, although it still works in section C.  I would like it was always be possible to open/close the sidebar clicking on the icon in the header. 
Second, now the right sidebar automatically opens when the app is loaded, while I'd prefer it to stay closed and let the user decide whether to open it or not.

Comment: Regarding the second issue, the sidebar automatically opens because the app has to select a tab on loading. A possible workaround would be to have something like Section 0 which will be the fist tab and wont need to have a second sidebar. As far as I can see it is not possible for an app to load without selecting a default tab.

Comment: This answer isn't working with shinydashboardPlus 2.0.0 and above - `rightSiderbarMenu()`, `rightSidebarTablist()`, `rightSidebarTabItem()`, `rightSidebarPanel()` and `rightSidebarTabContent()` were removed. They are now replaced by `dashboardControlbar()`, `controlbarMenu()` and `controlbarItem()`. See the [changelog](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/news/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to teofil's answer, you can use selector = "body" instead so the right sidebar can still be opened and closed.

```
shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use `shiny::tabsetPanel` instead of `shinydashboardPlus::rightSidebarTabContent`.

To use `tabsetPanel` inside of the right sidebar, but still look something like shinydashboard's right sidebar tabset panel requires some CSS styling include [removing the dark space at the top of the right sidebar panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289622/remove-the-dark-space-at-the-top-of-the-right-sidebar-in-a-shinydashboardplus) and [changing the 'active' and 'hover' colours of the tabpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025145/background-color-of-tabs-in-shiny-tabpanel).

Showing/hiding `tabPanel` merely requires using `showTab` and `hideTab`. It is possible to use the `select` argument of `showTab` to just select the tab, without necessarily hiding the other tabs.

As a bonus, I've also add a `rintrojs` walkthrough. As the code stands, the change in panels during the walkthrough can't be 'seen', but it is happening!

Thanks to CPB's answer, which showed the best way to show/hide the right sidebar.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(dashboardthemes)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  rintrojs::introjsUI(),
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "Dashboard",
    enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
    rightSidebarIcon = "info-circle"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Section A", tabName = "Section_A", icon = icon("map")),
      menuItem("Section B", tabName = "Section_B", icon = icon("chart-line")),
      menuItem("Section C", tabName = "Section_C", icon = icon( "gears")),
      id = "nav"
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    shinyDashboardThemes(
      theme = "grey_dark"
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_A",
        p("Some content for section A")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_B",
        p("Some content for section B")),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Section_C",
        p("Some content for section C"))
    ),
    shiny::actionButton("walkthrough", "Overview of tabs")
    # this will start an rintrojs walkthrough
  ),
  rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
    shiny::tags$head(shiny::tags$style(shiny::HTML(
      ".control-sidebar-tabs {display:none;}
    .tabbable > .nav > li > a:hover {background-color: #333e43; color:white}
    .tabbable > .nav > li[class=active] > a   {background-color: #222d32;  color:white}"))),
    # '{display:none;}' removes empty space at top of rightsidebar
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289622/
    #  remove-the-dark-space-at-the-top-of-the-right-sidebar-in-a-shinydashboardplus
    # '.tabbable etc.' change tabpanel tab colouring on hover and active to be
    # more like shinydashboardPlus::rightSidebarTabContent
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025145/
    #  background-color-of-tabs-in-shiny-tabpanel
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798850/
    #  change-background-color-of-tabpanel-when-it-is-active-or-hover-over-in-shiny
    useShinyjs(),

    background = "dark",
    shiny::tabsetPanel(
      id = "myrightpanel",
      shiny::tabPanel(
        shiny::icon("desktop"),
        value = "T_A",
        shiny::div(id = "first-panel",
                   p("Some content relevant for section A"),
                   sliderInput(
                     "obs",
                     "Number of observations:",
                     min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
                   ))
      ),
      shiny::tabPanel(
        shiny::icon("calendar-alt"),
        value = "T_B",
        p("Some content relevant for section B"),
        textInput("caption", "Caption", "Data Summary")
      )
    )
  ),
  title = "Right Sidebar"
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_A"){
      message("Section A has been selected")
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      shiny::showTab(inputId = "myrightpanel",
                     target = "T_A", select = TRUE)
      shiny::hideTab(inputId = "myrightpanel",
                     target = "T_B")
    }
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_B"){
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
      shiny::showTab(inputId = "myrightpanel",
                     target = "T_B", select = TRUE)
      shiny::hideTab(inputId = "myrightpanel",
                     target = "T_A")
    }
    if (req(input$nav) == "Section_C"){
      message("Section C has been selected")
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open")
    }
  })

  walkthrough_df <-
    data.frame(element = "#first-panel",
               intro = c(paste(shiny::tags$h4("My first tab"),
                               shiny::br(),
                               "Has a slider input")),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  walkthrough_df <-
    rbind(walkthrough_df,
          data.frame(element = "#caption",
                     intro = c(paste(shiny::tags$h4("My second panel text input"),
                                     shiny::br(),
                                     "Has a text input. The tabs has changed"))))

  walkthrough <- reactive(walkthrough_df)

  shiny::observeEvent(input$walkthrough, {
    shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "control-sidebar-open") # open right sidebar
    shiny::showTab(inputId = "myrightpanel", target = "T_A")
    shiny::showTab(inputId = "myrightpanel", target = "T_B") # show both tabs
    shinyjs::delay(1000, # need to delay for the above showTab changes to be enacted
                   rintrojs::introjs(session, options = list(steps = walkthrough(),
                                                             overlayOpacity = 0.3),
                                     events = list(onbeforechange = I("rintrojs.callback.switchTabs(targetElement)")))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```